# Using regex to match consonant letters

Tags: java, regex

I want to search for consonant letters that happens 3 times consecutive i.e "happy" matches, "read" doesn't match

It can be done by:

```
String str;
if (str.matches("\\S*([b-df-hj-nq-tv-z]){3,}\\S*"))
    System.out.println("yes");
else
    System.out.println("NO");
```

This code works but is there any way to do this using match a-z except `[a,e,i,o,u]`?

Comment: You overlooked the letter `p`.

Comment: You can use "[a-z&&[^aeiou]]", see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html

Comment: Be carefull, `[a,e,i,o,u]` is really `[aeiou,]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> match a-z except [a,e,i,o,u]

You can try using `[a-z&&[^aeiou]]`. `&&` is intersection of sets, so it is like intersection of `a-z` with characters which are not `a,e,i,o,u`.

Comment: grep: Invalid range end

Comment: @DrunkenMaster Based on http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclassintersect.html "Character class intersection is supported by Java and by Ruby 1.9 and later." so `grep` may not support it.  Maybe try with [subtraction](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclasssubtract.html) `[a-z-[aeiuo]]`. If this doesn't work you will probably have to use `[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]` (unless `grep` supports some syntax which I am not aware of).

Answer (score 3):

In Java you can use this regex i.e. `a through z except a, e, i, o, u`:

```
(?i)([a-z&&[^aeiou]]){3,}
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://fiddle.re/ebhxt)

#### [Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: `&&` is used in java for intersection

Comment: Intersection? From his question, he doesn't sound knowledgeable of regex. Sometimes its better to give an explanation. Otherwise, people think how did he get that from this `&&[]`

Comment: Precisely for that reason I have included a link to `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html` in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is class subtraction.

Do it the easy way. Internally its done like this.
Externally, you won't make a mistake.

```
 # "(?i)(?=[^aeiou]{3})[a-z]{3}"

 (?i)
 (?= [^aeiou]{3} )
 [a-z]{3}
```

Or you could reverse it for better performance, depending on what is the predominant text you expect.

```
 # "(?i)(?=[a-z]{3})[^aeiou]{3}"

 (?i)
 (?= [a-z]{3} )
 [^aeiou]{3}
```