# How do I simplify my solution to this ruby problem that asks for every consonant to be doubled in a given string?

Tags: regex, ruby, string

So the question asks that I "Write a method that takes a string, and returns a new string in which every consonant character is doubled.  Vowels (a,e,i,o,u), digits, punctuation and white space should not be doubled."  Well I quickly realized that a regular expression should do the trick, but i'm pretty new to such expressions and thus had to use an && operator to get my solution to work.  Now I'm sure it's an easy fix, but I was unable to create it so here's my solution to the problem:

```
def double_consonants(string)
  array = string.chars.map do |char| 
    if char =~ /[a-z]/i && char =~ /[^aeiou]/i
      char * 2
    else 
      char 
    end 
  end 
  array.join 
end
```

So double_consonants("Hello World!") correctly outputs "HHellllo WWorrlldd!" but i'm looking for a more terse solution.  I tried, [a-z^aeiou]/i and similar combinations but they also doubled the vowels.  So if someone can instruct me on how to combine the two expressions correctly, as well as explain to me why my rudimentary attempt was wrong, I would be extremely grateful.  Furthermore any suggestions or corrections to the rest of my code is also welcome.

Comment: Your answer works. `double_consonants('abcdefg') #=> "abbccddeffgg"`.

Comment: Try: `if char =~ /[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]/i`

Comment: Yes I know that my answer works but I was looking for a simpler solution that combines my two conditions, assuming it's possible. @SagarPandya

Comment: Thank you @Matt.G that worked, but to be honest I was looking for a working version of [a-z^aeiou]/i, more so to better understand the mechanics of regular expressions.

Comment: This `/[a-z&&[^aeiou]]/` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26026913/using-regex-to-match-consonant-letters). Then another way using gsub would be `str.gsub(/([a-z&&[^aeiou]])/i,'\1\1')`

Comment: A few very small points. 1) Since Ruby v2.4 you can write `char.match?(/[a-z]/i)` instead of  `char =~ /[a-z]/i`. The former arguably reads better, and returns a boolean, rather than a string index (you would not use) or `nil`. 2. You could write `char !~ /aeiou/i` instead of `char =~ /[^aeiou]/i`. (cont...)

Comment: ...3. `string.chars` returns a temporary array. As `map` is an `Enumerable` method it requires a receiver that is an enumerator, to you can instead write `string.each_char.map`, as `each_char` returns an enumerator rather than a temporary array, saving memory. Use `each_char` except when chaining to an `Array` method, in which case you must use `chars` (e.g., `string.chars.product(...)`).

Comment: Note that you don't need the variable `array`. Remove `array =` and `array.join`, and replace `end` that ends `map`'s block with `end.join`. Recall every block returns a value. Here's a variant that avoids the conversion to an array and the subsequent `join`, and also incorporates @Sagar's suggestion: `"Cats!".each_char.with_object('') { |c,s| s << (c.match?(/[a-z&&[^aeiou]]/i) ? c*2 : c) } # #=> "CCattss!"`. Incidentally, since your code works, your question is really more suitable for SO's sister site at Stack Exchange, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Have a look!

Comment: Thank you @SagarPanya your solution is the one closest to the solution that I envisioned.

Comment: @CarySwoveland you're a rockstar.  Your larger solution was very thorough and your suggestion to use the match? method instead of the =~ regex method makes perfect sense and is easier to work with.  By the way, I literally made a profile right before posting this problem and was shocked at the speed of the responses.  I want to thank you and everyone else that took time to help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MAPPING =
  (('a'..'z').to_a - %w|a e i o u|).
    each_with_object({}) do |s,h|
      h[s] = s + s
      h[s.upcase] = h[s].upcase
    end.tap { |h| h.default_proc = proc { |_,c| c } } 
  #=> {"b"=>"bb", "c"=>"cc", "d"=>"dd", "f"=>"ff",..."z"=>"zz",
  #    "B"=>"BB", "C"=>"CC", "D"=>"DD", "F"=>"FF",..."Z"=>"ZZ"} 

MAPPING['c']  #=> "cc" 
MAPPING['C']  #=> "CC" 
MAPPING['a']  #=> "a" 
MAPPING['$']  #=> "$" 

"Now is the time to party, said 007.".gsub(/./, MAPPING)
  #=> "NNoww iss tthhe ttimme tto pparrttyy, ssaidd 007."
```

This uses the form of [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) that employs a hash (`MAPPING`) to perform substitutions. `gsub`'s first argument, the regular expression `/./` causes each character of the string to be matched.

For this to work, `MAPPING[c]` (`c` a variable) must return `c` for every character `c` that is not a consonant. That is achieved by attaching a *default proc* (`proc { |_,c| c }`) to the hash. See [Hash#default_proc=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc-3D) and [Kernel#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-tap).

If several strings are to be converted, using a regex is relatively inefficient when compared to using a hash, as matching a character against a collection of consonants requires a linear search, whereas hash lookups are very fast, being relatively insensitive to the numbers of keys in the hash.

Answer (score 0):

if you need a regex solution similar to the one posted in question, try Regex: `(?=[a-z])(?![aeiou])(.)`

and replace with `\1\1`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gZGMmw/2)

Coming to the regex mentioned in the question: `[a-z^aeiou]` matches a single character in the range between `a (index 97)` and `z (index 122)` or `^` or `a` or `e` or `i` or `o` or `u` (case insensitive) (For more details see the description given in the top right corner in this [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gZGMmw/3))